# AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory

While I searched this error the solution was to grant permissions.While I am trying that I am unable to grant permissions for the app. 
Should I need to enable the delegated permissions for that app.

Comment: Please share code and details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It probably means you are trying to sign in as a non-admin user, and the app requests permissions that require admin permissions to grant. App permissions mostly require admin, some delegated as well. You could mention which permissions you have granted to your app.